# Risks of apt-installing package without doing an apt upgrade beforehand

Tags: apt, software-installation

In an Ansible playbook which automates a VPS setup I'm in the need to install `git` as soon as possible.

I want to do that before going through the entire `apt update && apt upgrade` procedure, so I want to first do an `apt update && apt install git`, then download some repositories which basically configure the shell, and later, when all users have been set up and their shells been configured, start with the real installing of applications, which is preceded by a `apt upgrade`.

Is this initial call to `apt install git` on a non-upgraded system problematic?

I've been told that an `apt upgrade` should be done before installing anything. What are the risks of not doing that?

Answer (score 1):

not much risk if you have done an update before. if there are libraries to be updated, you will be prompted to update them as well before installing the app you want to.